# how to integrate $e^{2t-\frac{3t^2}{2}}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

I tried power series and got :

$$ \int\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(4t-\frac{3}{2}t^2)}{n!}e^{2t-\frac{3t^2}{2}}dt$$

from there i got stuck.

Comment: Hi. Can you format (use MathJax)  it so the question is legible?

Answer (score 6):

Guessing you want $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{4t - \frac{3}{2}t^2} \,\mathrm{d}t$.

- Complete the square in the exponent.  This gives you a constant to move out of the integral.
- Make a linear change of variable to obtain $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-u^2} \,\mathrm{d}u$.  This gives you a constant to move out of the integral.
- Having reduced the integral to a standard form, write down its value.   $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-u^2} \,\mathrm{d}u = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: If you don't want the definite integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ but just an anti-derivative, complete the square as above, which gives, up to a constant, the erf function.